# Is there a way for a low level access to bluetooth device?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, battery

I am trying to find a way to read Bluetooth headphones battery level. It seems it is impossible through macOS itself, so I am looking for a way to do a low level read directly from the Bluetooth device.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that this pair of headphones supports headphone battery level? By default it should show in the Bluetooth dropdown for the device, so if it's not showing there, it may not be sending battery information at all, with no way to access it.

Comment: The device definitely supports battery level. iPhone or iPad correctly show battery level. On 10.13 tho, there is none listed, or shown. The device itself is BT 4.2.